# convert a SQL Query to Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

this is my first post, I'm working on converting a PHP Pure project to Laravel, and the client wants the report to work like the old project, and the report is SQL statement and I want to make/convert it into Laravel Query.
Note all query read from the patient table.

Table structure for table `patient`

```
CREATE TABLE `patient` (
  `idPatient` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idUser_Agent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientFName` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientLName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientDOB` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientGender` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientAddress` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientCity` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientState` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientZip` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientPhone` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientInsuranceName` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientInsurancePolicy` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientPhysicanFName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientPhysicanLName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientPhysicianAddress` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientPhysicianCity` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientPhysicianState` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientPhysicianZip` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientPhysicianPhone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `PatientPhysicianFax` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `PatientPhysicianNPI` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientHeight` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientWeight` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BraceLine1` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BL1From` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `BL1Type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BL1Modify` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BL1Size` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BraceLine2` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BL2From` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `BL2Type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BL2Modify` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BL2Size` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AmountPaid` decimal(32,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PaidDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `TrackingNumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TrackingNumber2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BL1Charges` decimal(32,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BL1Unit` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BL2Charges` decimal(32,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BL2Unit` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Comment` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateAdded` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientDO` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientRecording` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `PatientRecording2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `PatientRelative` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FormStatus` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AmountPaid2` decimal(32,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PaidDate2` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ReturnReason` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ModifiedDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmailShip1` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `EmailShip2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `FormSubStatus` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmailShip1Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmailShip2Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Return` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `DOStatus` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `DOSubStatus` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ShippedStatus` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ShippedStatus2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `BraceLine3` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BL3From` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `BL3Type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BL3Modify` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BL3Size` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BL3Unit` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BL3Charges` decimal(32,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AmountPaid3` decimal(32,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PaidDate3` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmailShip3` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `EmailShip3Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShippedStatus3` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PatientDO2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HMO` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HMOStatus` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PPO` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `Portal` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmailSchedule` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `RelativeType` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `BEVStatus` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `QAStatus` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Pending',
  `id_UserAgent_QA` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Catheters` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `CathetersType` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `CathetersSize` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `CathetersBrand` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Walker` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `WalkerType` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Reimbursement` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `R_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `CheckNo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `R_Amount` decimal(32,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DrCallMade` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StartDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `EndDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `PickupTrackingNumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PickupTrackingNumber2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BracePickup` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PickupReason` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PickupDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `FaxSent` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

the SQL query

```
SELECT
    SUM(pt1) AS SENT,
    SUM(pt2) AS DOBACK,
    SUM(pt2) * 100 / SUM(pt1 + pt2) AS percentage,
    DateAdded,
STATUS AS
    FormStatus
FROM
    (
        (
        SELECT
            1 AS Pt1,
            0 AS pt2,
            "SENT TO RX1" AS
        STATUS
            ,
            DateAdded
        FROM
            patient
        WHERE
            (dostatus = "Sent to RX1") AND(portal = "NationalRXGA")
    )
UNION ALL
    (
    SELECT
        0 AS p1,
        1 AS PatientNumbers2,
        "SENT TO RX1" AS
    STATUS
        ,
        DateAdded
    FROM
        patient
    WHERE
        (dosubstatus = "DO BACK") AND(portal = "NationalRXGA")
)
UNION ALL
    (
    SELECT
        1 AS PatientNumbers1,
        0 AS patientnumber2,
        "SENT TO RX2" AS
    STATUS
        ,
        DateAdded
    FROM
        patient
    WHERE
        (dostatus = "Sent to RX2") AND(portal = "NationalRXGA")
)
UNION ALL
    (
    SELECT
        0 AS p1,
        1 AS PatientNumbers2,
        "SENT TO RX2" AS
    STATUS
        ,
        DateAdded
    FROM
        patient
    WHERE
        (dosubstatus = "DO BACK") AND(portal = "NationalRXGA")
)
    ) AS t
GROUP BY
STATUS
```

Comment: Can't you just use `DB::raw` for now? Then figure out what the relationships are and start using Eloquent down the line?

Comment: You can expect people to convert the query for you, we can help you if you stuck anywhere while you trying out some solution.
For starter you can check the laravel documentation  about 
 unions and give it a try https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#unions

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things here:
Make stored procedure for your SQL query or Create View of patient table inthe mySQL.
It will help you converting to Laravel easily fetching data for your whole project & it will be optimal fast.